# Magento 2: How to use redirect in Router.php

Tags: controllers, redirect, cms, cms-pages, routing

I am trying to redirect a cms page to a custom controller.
in router.php
I can check the current URL, If the current URL is as an example if it matches /test-url i want to do a redirect to /test-url-router

```
    if ($identifier == 'test-url') {
       $this->_response->setRedirect('test-url-router');
       $request->setDispatched(true);
       return $this->actionFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Redirect::class);
    }
```

This works it does redirect me to test-url-router (the page will be 404)
I want to show my custom controller which I am not sure of how to get this working.

```
$request->setModuleName('custom') //module name
        ->setControllerName('custom') //controller name
        ->setActionName('index'); //action name;
```

is it possible to get this both working?

Comment: Delete the cms page with test-url and create routes.xml and configure your own route.

Answer (score 0):

Module name - **Inchoo_CustomRouter**

**Registration.php :: app/code/Inchoo/CustomRouter/registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Inchoo_CustomRouter', __DIR__
);
```

**Module.xml :: app/code/Inchoo/CustomRouter/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Inchoo d.o.o.
 * created by Zoran Salamun(zoran.salamun@inchoo.net)
 * Module is created for Custom Router demonstration
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Inchoo_CustomRouter" setup_version="2.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

**di.xml :: app/code/Inchoo/CustomRouter/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

</config>
```

**routes.xml :: app/code/Inchoo/CustomRouter/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="inchootest" frontName="inchootest">
            <module name="Inchoo_CustomRouter" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**di.xml :: app/code/Inchoo/CustomRouter/etc/frontend/di.xml**
Here we are passing the router file path and the sort order for the router

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="inchoocustomrouter" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Inchoo\CustomRouter\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">61</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Routes.php :: app/code/Inchoo/CustomRouter/Controller/Router.php**

```
<?php

namespace Inchoo\CustomRouter\Controller;

/**
 * Inchoo Custom router Controller Router
 *
 * @author      Zoran Salamun <zoran.salamun@inchoo.net>
 */
class Router implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory
     */
    protected $actionFactory;

    /**
     * Response
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface
     */
    protected $_response;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory, \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response
    ) {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
        $this->_response = $response;
    }

    /**
     * Validate and Match
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @return bool
     */
    public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request) {
        /*
         * You can use any name in URL and add condition for that name here to redirect it. Here we are accessing customrouting 
         * and if the we get the same, the we will redirect the request to controller action.
         * We will search “examplerouter” and “exampletocms” words and make forward depend on word
         * -examplerouter will forward to base router to match inchootest front name, test controller path and test controller class
         * -exampletocms will set front name to cms, controller path to page and action to view
         */
       // $a = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        // $postId = end($a);  [if you want to pass parameter also.]
        //exit;
        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
        if (strpos($identifier, 'exampletocms') !== false) {
            /*
             * We must set module, controller path and action name + we will set page id 5 witch is about us page on
             * default magento 2 installation with sample data.
             */
            $request->setModuleName('cms')->setControllerName('page')->setActionName('view')->setParam('page_id', 4); // specify the page id
        } else if (strpos($identifier, 'customrouting') !== false) {
            /*
             * We must set module, controller path and action name for our controller class(Controller/Test/Test.php)
             */
            $request->setModuleName('CustomRouter')->setControllerName('test')->setActionName('test');

            // $request->setParam('id', $postId); [if passing params]
        } else {
            //There is no match
            return;
        }

        /*
         * We have match and now we will forward action
         */
        return $this->actionFactory->create(
                        'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward', ['request' => $request]
        );
    }

}


/* you will face iteration error if the controller you are trying to access is not available*/
```

**Test.php :: app/code/Inchoo/CustomRouter/Controller/Test/Test.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Inchoo d.o.o.
 * created by Zoran Salamun(zoran.salamun@inchoo.net)
 */

namespace Inchoo\CustomRouter\Controller\Test;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    /**
     * Listing all images in gallery
     *  -@param gallery id
     */
    public function execute() {
        die("Inchoo\\CustomRouter\\Controller\\Test\\Test controller execute()");
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Gohil, i am using this right now but i can't change the url, my default url is test-url and i need to redirect to test-url-routing with a custom controller. the /test-url is cms page

Comment: why u wanna redirect cms page url? I dont get your requirement. but you can also create redirect rule in htaccess